# Testing controller methods protected from forgery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, authenticity-token

I'm trying to test a method I have in my application, but I don't know how to unit test a method that is being protected from forgery, take a look at this:

```
    def index
    @alumnos = Alumno.paginate :per_page => 20, 
      :page => params[:page], :order => :nombre

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @alumnos }
    end
  end
```

In the index.html.erb I have this line:

```
<%= javascript_tag "window._token = '#{form_authenticity_token}'" %>
```

So, when I try to test it with a functional test, it seems that the session doesn't have the secret work which will cause the test to fail, does anyone have experience testing this methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution (or a workaround) :
in your controllers/application.rb

```
   if RAILS_ENV =='test'
    protect_from_forgery  :secret => 'write ur secret in config/environment.rb'

  else

protect\_from_forgery

  end
```